# 2001 Toyota Rav4 O2 sensor change

Tags: toyota, o2-sensor, rav4, motor-mounts

When changing O2 sensor B1 S2 on 2001 rav4 do you have to loosen the engine mount to access sensor with o2 socket, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You can use a crows foot o2 sensor socket iirc. Or heat the pipe with a torch and use a 22mm wrench.

Comment: Thanks Ben, my crows foot sensor socket and new metric wrench set with a 22mm should arrive today, wish me luck.

Comment: Job is done, crows foot sensor socket, and 2 days WD 40 while I waited for my socket. It came of in seconds